# Trying to use knockoutjs to toggle checkbox when hovering

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to check/uncheck checkbox by `mouseover` event, but not having any luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="event: {mouseover: toggle}" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function AppViewModel() {
        self = this;
        self.toggle = function () { this.checked = true; }; //doesn't work :(
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "this" in the toggle function refers to the "function scope" and assigning the checked property there won't help much. I don't fully understand the final requirement here but if you wish to do all using pure binding and no DOM reference, you can modify your code as

```
 function AppViewModel() {
        self = this;
        self.checkedFlag=ko.observable();
        self.toggle = function () { 
            self.checkedFlag(true);
        }; //doesn't work :(
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

and your mark up as

```
 <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:checkedFlag,event: {mouseover: toggle}" />
```

and the check box would be checked on mouse over, here is the fiddler for your reference 
https://jsfiddle.net/cLu38jjt/1/

Comment: when you say "no DOM reference" would that make it easier?

Comment: I mean with out using the "cheked" binding and directly accessing the element in the toggle function. it would be something like this https://jsfiddle.net/cLu38jjt/2/

Comment: Maybe I should have expanded my example a little more. I added the concept to my simple list but not working. I'm trying to call the toggle function...https://jsfiddle.net/cLu38jjt/4/

Comment: what isn't working? https://jsfiddle.net/cLu38jjt/5/ when I hover on the checkbox it does toggle ... what is the expected outcome?

Comment: You're jsfiddle is slightly different in that it is using $root.toggle which works. Thanks again, I'll have to do more reading.

Comment: Ow yeah! I did add the toggle method from the $root. in my very first fiddle  the checkbox was bound directly on the view model that is why it worked. In your next fiddler the check box was bound to "seats" so to access the toggle method on the main view model I had to add "$root". .. just a little clarification  :) good luck!